# Dense subset of $C(X)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I am trying to prove the next proposition, but i need some help:

Let $ (X,\rho)$ be compact metric space. Prove that there exist a compact subset $K$ of $C(X)$ whose linear span is dense in $C(X)$

Thanks.

Comment: What is the linear span of $K$? I don't see any linear structure on $C(X)$.

Comment: @Alex: $C(X)$ is the space of continuous functions $X \to \mathbb{R}$...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ah, I forgot that convention. For some reason I was thinking of $C(X,X)$.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, $C(X)=C(X,R)$

Comment: Why are you trying to prove it? Are you sure it is true (i.e., is it an exercise from a book?)

Comment: You could try the set of all 1-Lipschitz functions bounded by 1. Use Arzelà-Ascoli and Stone-Weierstrass theorems.

Comment: @Thomas: is a qualifier problem.

Comment: @JulienB: What we get from the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem is that the $ \mathbb{R} $-subalgebra generated by the $ 1 $-Lipschitz functions is dense in $ C(X,\mathbb{R}) $. I do not see how we can deduce that the *$ \mathbb{R} $-linear span* of the $ 1 $-Lipschitz functions is dense in $ C(X,\mathbb{R}) $ from this result.

Answer (score 6):

Hints:

1. $C(X)$ is separable.
2. Given any sequence in a Banach space, you can rescale the terms of the sequence so that it converges to 0.
3. In any metric space. if $x_n \to x$, then $\{x_n\} \cup \{x\}$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

Nate's answer is slick, but I am a slow thinker who would not have been able to discover his route (I prefer the word *route* over the word *trick*, whose usage is subjective). I will give a solution that appeals only to the beginner analyst's knowledge of the Arzelà-Ascoli Theorem and the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem. This so happens to build upon Thomas' idea, which, unfortunately, he was not able to carry through to completion.

For each $ a \in A $, define a ‘distance’ function $ \phi_{a}: X \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} $ by
$$
\forall x \in X: \quad {\phi_{a}}(x) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \rho(a,x).
$$
Each $ \phi_{a} $ is clearly continuous. As $ (X,\rho) $ is a compact metric space, it is totally bounded, hence bounded. Consequently, the family of functions $ \mathcal{F} := \{ \phi_{a} \}_{a \in X} $ is uniformly bounded with respect to the sup-norm on $ C(X,\mathbb{R}) $. We can thus find a scalar constant $ M > 0 $ large enough so that the (continuous) function $ \psi_{a} := \dfrac{1}{M} \cdot \phi_{a} $ has sup-norm $ \leq 1 $ for each $ a \in A $. We now show that the family $ \mathcal{G} $ of continuous functions on $ X $ given by
$$
\mathcal{G} := \{ \psi_{a_{1}} \times \cdots \times \psi_{a_{n}} ~|~ n \in \mathbb{N} ~ \text{and} ~ a_{1},\ldots,a_{n} \in X \}
$$
is pointwise-bounded and equicontinuous.

- As the sup-norm of $ \psi_{a} $ for each $ a \in A $ is $ \leq 1 $, the same can be said of a finite product of such functions. This immediately yields the pointwise-boundedness of $ \mathcal{G} $.
- Choose $ a_{1},\ldots,a_{n} \in X $ and also $ x_{0} \in X $. Then
  \begin{align}
  \forall x \in X: \quad
       &|{\psi_{a_{1}}}(x_{0}) \times \cdots \times {\psi_{a_{n}}}(x_{0}) - {\psi_{a_{1}}}(x) \times \cdots \times {\psi_{a_{n}}}(x)| \\
  \leq &|{\psi_{a_{1}}}(x_{0}) \times \cdots \times {\psi_{a_{n}}}(x_{0})| + |{\psi_{a_{1}}}(x) \times \cdots \times {\psi_{a_{n}}}(x)| \\
  =    &|{\psi_{a_{1}}}(x_{0})| \cdots |{\psi_{a_{n}}}(x_{0})| + |{\psi_{a_{1}}}(x)| \cdots |{\psi_{a_{n}}}(x)| \\
  \leq &|{\psi_{a_{1}}}(x_{0})| + |{\psi_{a_{1}}}(x)| \quad (\text{$ \| \psi_{a} \|_{\infty} \leq 1 $ for each $ a \in X $.}) \\
  =    &\frac{1}{M} \cdot \rho(a_{1},x_{0}) + \frac{1}{M} \cdot \rho(a_{1},x) \\
  =    &\frac{1}{M} \cdot \rho(x_{0},a_{1}) + \frac{1}{M} \cdot \rho(a_{1},x) \\
  =    &\frac{1}{M} [\rho(x_{0},a_{1}) + \rho(a_{1},x)] \\
  \leq &\frac{1}{M} \cdot \rho(x_{0},x). \quad (\text{By the Triangle Inequality.})
  \end{align}
  Hence, for any $ \epsilon > 0 $, if we set $ \delta := M \epsilon $, then for any $ x \in X $ satisfying $ \rho(x_{0},x) < \delta $, we will surely have
  $$
  |{\psi_{a_{1}}}(x_{0}) \times \cdots \times {\psi_{a_{n}}}(x_{0}) - {\psi_{a_{1}}}(x) \times \cdots \times {\psi_{a_{n}}}(x)| < \epsilon.
  $$
  As $ \delta $ works for any choice of $ a_{1},\ldots,a_{n} \in X $, and as $ x_{0} $ is arbitrary, the equicontinuity of $ \mathcal{G} $ is therefore established.

Now, by the Arzelà-Ascoli Theorem, the sup-norm closure of $ \mathcal{G} $, which we denote by $ \overline{\mathcal{G}} $, must be a compact subset of $ C(X,\mathbb{R}) $. It remains to show that its linear span is dense.

Assuming that $ X $ contains more than one point (if $ X $ is a singleton set, then $ C(X,\mathbb{R}) $ is homeomorphic to $ \mathbb{R} $, so just use the obvious fact that the $ \mathbb{R} $-linear span of the compact singleton set $ \{ 1 \} $ is dense in $ \mathbb{R} $), we see that:

(1) $ \mathcal{G} $ separates points in $ X $.

**Explanation:** Given distinct $ x,y \in X $, observe that $ {\psi_{x}}(x) = \dfrac{1}{M} \cdot \rho(x,x) = 0 $, whereas $ {\psi_{x}}(y) = \dfrac{1}{M} \cdot \rho(x,y) \neq 0 $.

(2) $ \mathcal{G} $ vanishes at no point of $ X $.

**Explanation:** Given any $ x \in X $, observe that $ \psi_{y} $ does not vanish at $ x $ if $ y \neq x $.

These two conditions fulfilled, we can apply the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem to deduce that the $ \mathbb{R} $-algebra generated by $ \mathcal{G} $ is a dense subset of $ C(X,\mathbb{R}) $. However, this $ \mathbb{R} $-algebra is simply the $ \mathbb{R} $-linear span of $ \mathcal{G} $, because $ \mathcal{G} $ was deliberately designed to be closed under finite products (this is the crux of the solution; you may call it a trick, if you want). Therefore, the $ \mathbb{R} $-linear span of $ \overline{\mathcal{G}} $, which contains the $ \mathbb{R} $-linear span of $ \mathcal{G} $, must also be dense in $ C(X,\mathbb{R}) $. We are therefore done.

As can be seen, the solution here gives a pretty explicit construction of a compact subset of $ C(X,\mathbb{R}) $ with the desired properties.

Answer (score 1):

**This is an answer to Dan's question and Haskell Curry's comment.**

Let $K$ be the set of $1$-Lipschitz functions $f\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ with $\sup_X |f| \leq 1$.

> **Lemma 1.** $K$ is a compact subset of $C(X)$.

*Hint.* Use Arzelà-Ascoli theorem.

> **Lemma 2.** The linear span of $K$ is the set of bounded Lipschitz functions $X\to \mathbb{R}$.

*Proof.* If $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $k$-Lipschitz function bounded by $M > 0$, then $f \in \max\{k,M\} K$. The conclusion follows from lemma 3.

> **Lemma 3.** The set of bounded Lipschitz functions $X\to \mathbb{R}$ is a subalgebra of $C(X)$.

*Hint.* Use the following triangle inequalities:
$$
|(f(x) + \lambda g(x)) - (f(y) + \lambda g(y))| \leq |f(x)-f(y)| + |\lambda| |g(x) - g(y)|
$$
and
$$
|f(x)g(x) - f(y)g(y)| \leq |g(x)||f(x)-f(y)| + |f(y)||g(x)-g(y)|.
$$

> **Lemma 4.** The set of bounded Lipschitz functions $X\to \mathbb{R}$ is a *dense* subset of $C(X)$.

*Hint.* Use lemma 3 and Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: Thanks for following up on my comment. This definitely makes much more sense.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. @JulienB: Thanks for your elegant solution.